# Helpers and Partials

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello Everyone i am new to rails can anyone answer my given questions
 **1. How to write a partial and helpers in rails 3 please tell me with a simple example..**
**2.How can i use Jquery .html within a rails form ..**
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read some books/do some research before asking this sort of question. Or even just read the APIs

Comment: Please tell me some links where i can clear my concepts..thanks

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html This might me helpfull as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official rails documentation for partials is here
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

This is a free and excellent book on rails. This link is to the section specific to partials.
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec:partials

This books is an awesome guide for rails and has good stuff about partials if you are ok with spending a buck
http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

Good luck in your rails endeavors